# Choose monochromatic scheme from "Change Colors" menu in python pptx

Tags: python-pptx

I have found the documentation for changing chart *styles* and for changing series colors point-by-point, but I haven't found anything about choosing colors from the "Change colors" menu. I specifically want to change to a monochromatic color scheme, using the color choices provided by PowerPoint when doing so.

[image: Change Colors Menu]

This is important because the documents I'm creating are going to people who do not understand how it's constructed on the back end—they just want to manipulate the data, so flexible color is best.

I'm guessing that this requires changing the XML directly?

With the first (blue) monochromatic style applied, these lines are added to the XML.

```
<p:extLst><p:ext uri="{D42A27DB-BD31-4B8C-83A1-F6EECF244321}"><p14:modId xmlns:p14="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/powerpoint/2010/main" val="4058498100"/></p:ext></p:extLst>
```

But I'm not sure how to call these to edit them. I there documentation somewhere of this process?

Is it similar to editing table styles?

```
def table_formatting(table, shape, ic):
    tbl = shape._element.graphic.graphicData.tbl
    if ic == 'TABLE':
        style_id = '{8EC20E35-A176-4012-BC5E-935CFFF8708E}'
    else:
        style_id = '{2D5ABB26-0587-4C30-8999-92F81FD0307C}'
    tbl[0][-1].text = style_id
```

Comment: Is this for creating a new presentation or are you trying to change the theme of an existing presentation?

Comment: This is creating a new presentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a better way to get the effect I needed automatically, using Python pptx's chart style option:

```
def createchart(chart_data, intendedchart):
    graphic_frame = placeholder.insert_chart(v.charttypelist[intendedchart], chart_data)
    chart = graphic_frame.chart
    chart.chart_style = 3
```

Comment: The above worked perfectly for me. I now have the monochrome style I was after.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest approach is to create a new empty presentation with the characteristics you want each of your generated presentations to have, including theme colors and slide layouts, etc. One way to do this is to create and save an empty presentation in PowerPoint, after selecting one of the "built-in" themes/templates available on the New Presentation screen.

Then create presentations from that "template" PPTX file:

```
prs = Presentation("my-template.pptx")
```

You probably want to delete all the slides from the "template" PPTX file. Any new slides you add will be appended after any slides that are there. Calling `Presentation()` like this essentially makes a copy of that named presentation and uses that as your starting point.

Calling `prs = Presentation()` does the same thing, it just uses a default template presentation contained in the `python-pptx` package.

Comment: Sorry. I wasn't clear in my status with Python-pptx.

I've already created a program that reads excel files and drops charts into PowerPoint using placeholders in multiple layouts. I've set up the template already, with a corporate color palette.It formats the fonts/sizes/etc.

What I need to be able to do is assign a monochromatic color scheme, as those are more accessible for different vision capabilities.

Comment: Continued—In previous iterations of this program, I iterated over a list of brand colors to assign specific values. That's not the best solution here, because contrast should be maximized in monochrome charts. PowerPoint's color options make these adjustments automatically, where a manual assignation would require a convoluted calculation that wouldn't adjust with data manipulation after the fact (a reality I must deal with). Even being pointed to how to edit the XML with Python would be helpful, as I'm clueless on that front.

Answer (score 0):

I lieu of changing the color palette for charts, which doesn't seem feasible right now, I'm creating a dictionary of preferred color choices using the same RGB values as would be automatically assigned by PowerPoint, then iterating over each point to change the color.

```
def seriescolor_formatting(chart, intended_chart, catlen, slen):
if intended_chart == 'PIE':
    for sc, series in enumerate(chart.series):
        for i, point in enumerate(series.points):
            point = chart.series[sc].points[i]
            fill = point.format.fill
            fill.solid()
            fill.fore_color.rgb = v.brand_colors[catlen][i]
else:
    for i, series in enumerate(chart.series):
        fill = series.format.fill
        fill.solid()
        fill.fore_color.rgb = v.brand_colors[slen][i]
```

Because I'm self taught, this is likely messier than it needs to be. I plan to refactor the code once it's working, so any comments that you think might help the structure or approach will be read and appreciated.